# Assign Form Value Using Javascript From PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I want to assign a value to a form in a PhoneGap application using javascript that is passed from a PHP file.

I tried something like this:

Javascript:

```
$('#email1').load("http://www.website.com/app/emailforform.php?action="+document.getElementById('email1').value);
```

Form:

```
<input type = "text" id = "email1" name="email1" value="" />
```

Do I need to get the data using AJAX or is there a simple solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using ajax is most likely your best bet on this one.

Comment: Are these scripts on the same page?

Comment: JS and form are on same page. Php is separate.

Comment: The way your script is set up, it seems you are setting the value of `email1` with the value of `email1`...this doesn't make sense. Can you describe the logic you are trying to implement?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to put in a DIV first. Not exactly sure. Have it working now though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.

Ended up using:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://www.website.com/app/emailforform.php',
success: function(data) {
$('#email1').val(data);
},
error: function() {
alert('Did not work');
}
});
```

Puts the value into the form as I was hoping.